# CASE statement in a DECLARE CURSOR

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, cursor, case

I want to declare a cursor that looks at a different table depending on a switch passed as a parameter to a stored procedure.

That is, something like the following:

```
DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR
   CASE
     WHEN @sname = 'A_database'
     THEN select a,b,c from [a].dbo.[mytable];
     WHEN @sname = 'B_database'
     THEN select a,b,c from [b].dbo.[mytable];
   END
```

I know this is the wrong syntax, but I hope you can infer my meaning and explain how one should do this sort of thing.

Comment: Does the rest of the procedure need to address whatever database it starts in?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cursor variable as follows:

```
DECLARE @curs CURSOR

IF @sname = 'A_database'
   SET @curs = CURSOR FOR 
                  select a,b,c from [a].dbo.[mytable];
ELSE IF @sname = 'B_database'
   SET @curs = CURSOR FOR
                  select a,b,c from [b].dbo.[mytable];

OPEN @curs

... etc
```